# Horizontally aligning text a certain distance from the margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins

I am making examination questions, and would like to align the question numbers across the question paper.

This is my effort so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newcommand{\RNum}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}
\setsansfont{Times New Roman} \fontsize{11.5pt}{13.8pt}\selectfont

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent \textbf{Formatting for Questions} \\
\\
\textbf{1} \hspace{0.5495cm} \textbf{(a)} \hspace{0.2cm} Question here \\
\hspace*{0.8525cm} \textbf{(a)} \hspace{0.1525cm} Question here \\
\hspace*{1.6775cm} Question here \\
\hspace*{0.8525cm} \textbf{(a)} \hspace{0.14cm} \textbf{(i)} \hspace{0.1485cm} Question here \\
\hspace*{0.8525cm} \textbf{(b)} \hspace{0.1175cm} \textbf{(i)} \hspace{0.1485cm} Question here \\
\hspace*{0.8525cm} \textbf{(d)} \hspace{0.1175cm} \textbf{(i)} \hspace{0.1485cm} Question here \\
\hspace*{1.6645cm} \textbf{(i)} \hspace{0.15cm} Question here \\
\hspace*{1.55175cm} \textbf{(ii)} \hspace{0.15cm} Question here \\
\hspace*{1.43925cm} \textbf{(iii)} \hspace{0.1515cm} Question here \\
\hspace*{2.4cm} Question here \\
\hspace*{0.8525cm} \textbf{(b)} \hspace{0.1285cm} Question here \\
\hspace*{0.8525cm} \textbf{(c)} \hspace{0.17375cm} Question here \\
\hspace*{0.8525cm} \textbf{(d)} \hspace{0.12825cm} Question here \\
\hspace*{0.8525cm} \textbf{(e)} \hspace{0.1735cm} Question here \\
\hspace*{0.865cm} Question here
\end{document}
```

As seen above, I have been using `\hspace` to align the question numbers, but it is rather inefficient and slightly inaccurate given the endless combinations of sub-questions.

My goal is for the following:
[image]

1. `(a)`, `(b)`, `(d)`, etc. to **start** at the red line (not end together)
2. Second column `Question here`, `(i)` to **start** at the blue line (ignoring `(ii)` and `(iii)`)
3. `(i)`, `(ii)`, `(iii)`, etc. to **end** at the green line (not start together)
4. Fourth column `Question here` to **start** at the yellow line

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome. I don't know if I understood your problem correctly. But the enumitem package allows enumerations to be aligned natively. [enumitem package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)

Comment: @AndréC Hi, could you tell me which part of my question that you found hard to understand? Apologies about my bad fluency.

Comment: I didn't understand if you want to draw the blue, red and green vertical lines or not.

Comment: Valid question. I do not require the lines to be drawn. I did it to make it easier to show how I wanted the numbers/letters to line up.

Comment: @AndréC Could you give me an example of how the enumitem package can be used? As far as I know, it is used for numbered/bulleted lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enumitem package allows questions to be aligned natively. With the `shortlabels`

option, you can simply modify the labels by adding the desired type of label.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newcommand{\RNum}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}
%\setsansfont{Times New Roman} \fontsize{11.5pt}{13.8pt}\selectfont

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent \textbf{Formatting for Questions} \\
\\

\begin{enumerate}[1,leftmargin=10mm]
\item  Question here 
\item Question here 
\item \begin{enumerate}[(a),leftmargin=18pt]
        \item  Question here 
        \item Question here 
        \item  Question here 
            \begin{enumerate}[(i),leftmargin=16pt]
            \item  Question here 
            \item Question here 
            \item  Question here 
            \item Question here 
            \end{enumerate}
        \item Question here 
        \end{enumerate}
\item  Question here 
\item Question here 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Now I understand, but is there a way to set a distance from the margin for each indent? How do make the second column start the same distance from the margin?

Comment: Yes it is possible, I updated the code and the screenshot to put the same margin everywhere so you can see the effect, but you can change each of the margins separately.

Comment: The (i) category is correct. However, I would like the (a), (b), (c), etc. to start at the same margin instead of ending there.

Comment: Do you want the `(a)` to start at the same margin as `3` or as `(i)`?

Comment: I would like the `(a)`, `(b)`, etc. to start at the same margin as the `Question here` after the `2`.

Comment: Just change the margin. I changed `leftmargin=18pt` to align it as you want in my answer.

Comment: I meant that I would like them to start together at that margin instead of ending together. The ending point of the closing brackets can be different but the starting point of the opening brackets should be the same.

Comment: I don't understand, can you add an image to your question to illustrate what you want?

Comment: I have edited the question to a hopefully more clearer illustration. I will explain here in other words in case you still do not get the message. For (a), (b), etc., I want the `(` to **start** at the red line but for (i), (ii), etc., I want the `)` to **end** at the green line.

Comment: If I understood correctly, it is still enough to modify the parameter `leftmargin`. Here I set it to `16pt` so that the __opening parenthesis__ of the `(i)` lines up with `Question here.`

Comment: The (i) is fine, the problem is with the (a), (b), etc.. Right now the closing parenthesis are lined up, but I want the opening parenthesis to line up instead.

Comment: To put it another way, I want the bullet points to **start** together instead of ending together.

Comment: There is no bullet point in my solution nor in your question, there are labels.

Comment: I was referring to the labels.

Comment: What labels are you talking about? Those `1 2 3`, those `(a) (b)` or those `(i)(ii)`?

Comment: I was referring to the `1 2 3` and `(a) (b)` labels.

Comment: This is a new problem. Ask a new question and if my answer to your question suits you, accept it. Other contributors will be able to help you.

Comment: Fair point. Thanks for your help.